# How to loop array inside string

Tags: loops, go, foreach, range

I have string like this

```
    data := `["452","767","406","535","908"]`
```

i want output like this

```
452
767
406
535
908
```

I try with

```
for _, s := range data {
        fmt.Println(s)

    }
```

but the result is

91
34
52
53
50
34
44
34
55
54
55
34
44
34
52
48
54
34
44
34
53
51
53
34
44
34
57
48

Comment: Your code is syntactically invalid.

Comment: sorry typo, i hve change the code

Comment: Are you asking how to parse a JSON array?

Answer (score 2):

Parse it as a JSON string.

```
    data := `["452","767","406","535","908"]`

    s := []string{}

    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(data), &s)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        fmt.Println(s[i])
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```golang
package main

import (
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func main() {
    data := `["452","767","406","535","908"]`
    tokens := strings.FieldsFunc(data, unicode.IsPunct)
    for _, token := range tokens {
        println(token)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
452
767
406
535
908
```